# How to sort results by conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

I have lots of keywords - "b1,b2,b3,a1,z1" which later would be composed as a query condition to do a query from a database.

It's like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sometable
 WHERE id IN (b1,b2,b3,a1,z1)
```

But the search results are a mess in order.

```
    ID
------------   
    a1
    b2
    b3
    b1
    z1
```

The question is how to make the search results are presented perfectly as  b1,b2,b3,a1,z1

Comment: have you looked at the order by predicate?

Comment: How do you receive these keywords? If this is a stored procedure, you may create a local variable table with an identity PK and then do a join against it and order by that field.

Comment: are you using any CSV splitter to split the key words into list ?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `charindex()`:

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(255)) + ',', ',b1,b2,b3,a1,z1,')
```

Another method is to use `join`:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM sometable s JOIN
     (VALUES ('b1', 1), ('b2', 2), ('b3', 3), ('a1', 4), ('z1', 5)
     ) v(id, priority)
     ON s.id = v.id
ORDER BY v.priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID is always a character plus a single digit number you can use this. You need to adjust the numbers if they can contain more than 1 character or more than 1 digit numbers.

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 1)
, SUBSTRING(ID, 2, 1)
```